# Visual Studio, how add new item from online template?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 when you click Add > New Item you can search for online template. Is it normal that I never see template. This section is always empty? Is this functionality not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running visual studio with /installVSTemplates (and with elevated permissions)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Registers project or item templates that are located in <Visual Studio installation path>\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\ or <Visual Studio installation path>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\ I'm talking of online template

Comment: According to Fiddler, when you activate the Online Templates window, it starts talking to i1.visualstudiogallery.msdn.s-msft.com. Does that happen on your side?